# Splitting paragraphs into sentences with regexp and PHP

Tags: php, regex, text-segmentation

I'm a regexp noob and trying to split paragraphs into sentences. In my language we use quite a bit of abbreviations (like: bl.a.) in the middle of sentences, so I have come to the conclusion, that what I need to do is to look for punctuations, that are followed by a single space and then a word that starts with a capital letter like:

```
[sentence1]...anymore. However...[sentence2]
```

So a paragraph like:

```
Der er en lang og bevæget forhistorie bag lov om varsling m.v. i forbindelse med afskedigelser af større omfang. Det er ikke en bureaukratisk lovtekst blandt så mange andre.
```

Should end in this output:

```
[0] => Der er en lang og bevæget forhistorie bag lov om varsling m.v. i forbindelse med afskedigelser af større omfang.
[1] => Det er ikke en bureaukratisk lovtekst blandt så mange andre.
```

and NOT this:

```
[0] => Der er en lang og bevæget forhistorie bag lov om varsling m.v. 
[1] => i forbindelse med afskedigelser af større omfang.
[2] => Det er ikke en bureaukratisk lovtekst blandt så mange andre.
```

I have found a solution that does the first part of this with the positive lookbehind feature:

```
$regexp = (?<=[.!?] | [.!?][\'"]);
```

and then

```
$sentences = preg_split($regexp, $paragraph, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

which is a great starting point, but splits way too many times because of the many abbreviations.

I have tried to do this:

```
(?<=[.!?]\s[A-Z] | [.!?][\'"])
```

to target every occurance of either

```
. or ! or ?
```

followed by a space and a capital letter, but that did not work.

Does anyone know, if there is a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: So you want to create a newline break whenever the criteria of 'This. Is'?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm quite satisfied with the output format of the preg_split PHP function. What I struggle with is writing the regexp that looks for the 'This. Is' criteria.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have actually read through those exact answers before posting, but I could not find any of them, that searches for the exact pattern of a punctiation followed by a space followed by a word that starts with a capital letter. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Ka, I have updated the question with an example of the output I am lookin for.

Comment: @ka: No, this question is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: by the RegExps you're using I see you have/want support for quotes ["\'], you also need this? can you provide an example where you want to split by quotes, and one you don't

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Ka, your answer works perfectly. You are right I do need support for quotes, but I think I figured that part out after seeing your solution. The regexp now looks like this = (?<=[.?!;]|[.?!;][\'"])\s+(?=\p{Lu}). Does that look somewhat right to you?

Comment: @acrmuui yes, looks good but you don't have quote usage in the example you posted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unicode RegExp for splitting sentences: `(?<=[.?!;])\s+(?=\p{Lu})`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/iR7cC8

Comment: "Unicode" here is misleading. This regex does makes use of Unicode Character Properties, but this does **not** implement the Unicode Sentence Boundary rules as defined by UAX 29.

Comment: @NikiC it's not foolproof indeed but UAX29 also notes: *...implementations are free to override (tailor) the results to meet the requirements ...*

Comment: Doesn't work on "e.g." though and "2. text here". It shouldn't split here

Comment: @tjvg1991 indeed, this is just a generic solution, you can add those special cases over the regex

Answer (score 3):

Searching for such a pattern still seems unreliable but as sentences may be ended by line returns I would try just the following

```
[.\!\?][\s\n\r\t][A-Z]
```

I don't think you actually meant for the look-ahead's do you? ( !? together, so using the \ escapes it - tells the regex ignore any special meaning )

Comment: @ka In theory it contains both, in practice I've found varied results using different java/php versions/methods