# componentsseparatedbystring by multiple separators in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, split

So here is the string `s`:

```
"Hi! How are you? I'm fine. It is 6 p.m. Thank you! That's it."
```

I want them to be separated to a array as:

```
["Hi", "How are you", "I'm fine", "It is 6 p.m", "Thank you", "That's it"]
```

Which means the separators should be `". "` + `"? "` + `"! "`

I've tried:

```
let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ".?!")
let array = s.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet)
```

But it will separate `p.m.` to two elements too. Result:

```
["Hi", " How are you", " I'm fine", " It is 6 p", "m", " Thank you", " That's it"]
```

I've also tried

```
let array = s.componentsSeparatedByString(". ")
```

It works well for separating `". "` but if I also want to separate `"? "`, `"! "`, it become messy.

So any way I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: The easy way is to use `componentsSeparatedByString`, but it will still fail. Since not every sentence ends with a space.

Comment: @RMenke i've tried `let array = s.componentsSeparatedByString(". ")`
It works well for separating `". "` but if I also want to separate `"? "`, `"! "`, it become messy.

Comment: I know, read my comment to the end ;)

Comment: @RMenke just ignore the last sentence in the string which is not ends with a space. How can I separate the previous sentences? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a method provided that lets you enumerate a string. You can do so by words or sentences or other options. No need for regular expressions.

```
let s = "Hi! How are you? I'm fine. It is 6 p.m. Thank you! That's it."
var sentences = [String]()
s.enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.startIndex..<s.endIndex, options: .BySentences) { 
    substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop in
    sentences.append(substring!)
}
print(sentences)
```

The result is:

> ["Hi! ", "How are you? ", "I\'m fine. ", "It is 6 p.m. ", "Thank you! ", "That\'s it."]

Comment: so `BySentences` is a function included in system itself?

Comment: Yes. See the docs for `NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`.

Answer (score 3):

rmaddy's answer is correct (+1). A Swift 3 implementation is:

```
var sentences = [String]()

string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex ..< string.endIndex, options: .bySentences) { substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop in
    sentences.append(substring!)
}
```

---

You can also use regular expression, [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRegularExpression), though it's much hairier than rmaddy's `.bySentences` solution. In Swift 3:

```
var sentences = [String]()

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(^|\\s+)(\\w.*?[.!?]+)(?=(\\s+|$))")
regex.enumerateMatches(in: string, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count)) { match, flags, stop in
    sentences.append((string as NSString).substring(with: match!.rangeAt(2)))
}
```

Or Swift 2:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(^|\\s+)(\\w.*?[.!?]+)(?=(\\s+|$))", options: [])
var sentences = [String]()
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count)) { match, flags, stop in
    sentences.append((string as NSString).substringWithRange(match!.rangeAtIndex(2)))
}
```

The `[.!?]` syntax matches any of those three characters. The `|` means "or". The `^` matches the start of the string. The `$` matches the end of the string. The `\\s` matches a whitespace character. The `\\w` matches a "word" character. The `*` matches zero or more of the preceding character. The `+` matches one or more of the preceding character. The `(?=)` is a look-ahead assertion (e.g. see if there's something there, but don't advance through that match).

I've tried to simplify this a bit, and it's still pretty complicated. Regular expressions offer rich text pattern matching, but, admittedly, it is a little dense when you first use it. But this rendition matches (a) repeated punctuation (e.g. `"Thank you!!!"`), (b) leading spaces, and (c) trailing spaces, too.

Answer (score 2):

If the splitting basis is something a little more esoteric than sentences, this extension could work.

```swift
extension String {
    public func components(separatedBy separators: [String]) -> [String] {
        var output: [String] = [self]
        for separator in separators {
            output = output.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: separator) }
        }
        return output.map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}
    }
}

let artists = "Rihanna, featuring Calvin Harris".components(separated by: [", with", ", featuring"])
```

Comment: This is a very good solution! But I need only the first occurrence of each set of characters. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a regex to solve this too: `(([^.!?]+\s)*\S+(\.|!|\?))`
Here the explanation from [regexper](http://regexper.com/#((%5B%5E.!%3F%5D%2B%5Cs)*%5CS%2B(%5C.%7C!%7C%5C%3F))) and an [example](http://regexr.com/3cdai)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found a regex too from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853733/2603230)

```
var pattern = "(?<=[.?!;…])\\s+(?=[\\p{Lu}\\p{N}])"

let s = "Hi! How are you? I'm fine. It is 6 p.m. Thank you! That's it."

let sReplaced = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(pattern, withString:"[*-SENTENCE-*]" as String, options:NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)

let array = sReplaced.componentsSeparatedByString("[*-SENTENCE-*]")
```

Perhaps it's not a good way as it has to first replace and than separate the string. :)

**UPDATE:**

For regex part, if you also want to match Chinese/Japanese punctuations (which space after each punctuation is not necessary), you can use the following one:

```
((?<=[.?!;…])\\s+|(?<=[。！？；…])\\s*)(?=[\\p{L}\\p{N}])
```